# C4365: 'return': conversion from 'std::size_t' to 'Py_ssize_t', signed/unsigned mismatch error

Tags: python, visual-studio, pyodbc, python-3.8

I'm getting a strange error when attempting to install pyodbc on my local machine in command prompt. Some sort of conversion error that might relate to Visual Studio? Any help would be appreciated. I'm running Python 3.8.2.

```
C:\Users\****.****\OneDrive\PythonProjects\venv\Scripts>pip install pyodbc
Collecting pyodbc
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/81/0d/bb08bb16c97765244791c73e49de9fd4c24bb3ef00313aed82e5640dee5d/pyodbc-4.0.30.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: pyodbc
  Running setup.py install for pyodbc ... error
    Complete output from command C:\Users\****.****\OneDrive\PythonProjects\venv\Scripts\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\****.****\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-4nnxqm8v\\pyodbc\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\****.****\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-9ksqmk4o\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers C:\Users\****.****\OneDrive\PythonProjects\venv\include\site\python3.8\pyodbc:
    running install
    running build
    running build_ext
    building 'pyodbc' extension
    creating build
    creating build\temp.win32-3.8
    creating build\temp.win32-3.8\Release
    creating build\temp.win32-3.8\Release\src
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DPYODBC_VERSION=4.0.30 -IC:\Users\****.****\OneDrive\PythonProjects\venv\include -IC:\Users\****.****\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\include -IC:\Users\****.****\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\winrt" /EHsc /Tpsrc\buffer.cpp /Fobuild\temp.win32-3.8\Release\src\buffer.obj /Wall /wd4514 /wd4820 /wd4668 /wd4711 /wd4100 /wd4127 /wd4191 /d2FH4-
    buffer.cpp
    c:\users\****.****\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\include\cpython/abstract.h(77): warning C4365: 'return': conversion from 'std::size_t' to 'Py_ssize_t', signed/unsigned mismatch
    fatal error C1007: unrecognized flag '-FH4-' in 'p2'
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 1

    ----------------------------------------
Command "C:\Users\****.****\OneDrive\PythonProjects\venv\Scripts\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\****.****\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-4nnxqm8v\\pyodbc\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\****.****\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-9ksqmk4o\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers C:\Users\****.****\OneDrive\PythonProjects\venv\include\site\python3.8\pyodbc" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\****.****\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-4nnxqm8v\pyodbc\
```

Answer (score 0):

The message you cite in your question title is just a warning.

> warning C4365: 'return': conversion from 'std::size_t' to 'Py_ssize_t', signed/unsigned mismatch

Such warnings are not unusual when building pyodbc from source on Windows.

The actual error is

> fatal error C1007: unrecognized flag '-FH4-' in 'p2'
> error: command 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\cl.exe' failed with exit status 1

and that's because your version of Visual Studio is too old to build pyodbc for Python 3.8. According to …

[Building pyodbc from source](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Building-pyodbc-from-source#windows)

… Visual Studio 2019 (version 16) is required, but you appear to have Visual Studio 2015 (version 14).

The strange thing is that `pip` is trying to build from source when pyodbc 4.0.30 already has a Windows wheel for 32-bit Python 3.8

[pyodbc-4.0.30-cp38-cp38-win32.whl](https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/85/b4/605710a72fb731a0b8445d19f2e937da16d94bb2fbc3006babdfd1122a7d/pyodbc-4.0.30-cp38-cp38-win32.whl)

You could try downloading that and then running

```
pip install pyodbc-4.0.30-cp38-cp38-win32.whl
```